# Customize DatePicker Windows Phone 8.1 universal

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

Is it possible to customize this part of the DatePicker?

[image]

Comment: What are you actually looking for? Changing colors? Changing inital date?....

Comment: I'd like to change the background color and the text color, and show always the rest of the months, days and years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not adjust the colors and appereance of the dialog in Windows Phone 8.1 that is compatible with Universal Windows Platforms.

There are may be customizations possible in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight. But I don't recommend you to switch over to this technology. And I also don't know how good these customizations work.